# Curry howard Isomorphism what the propositions A , B ranges over

Tags: logic, type-theory, curry-howard

In CH-I what the propositions A , B ranges over too ?

An update :

From Pfennings notes :

"A denotes proposition about the mathematical objects such as integer or a real number."

From :
 Per martin lof "On the meanings of logical constant" pdf cs.cmu.edu/~crary/819-f09/Martin-Lof83.pdf , 17-18 page 
"We may substitute for A and B now range over arbitrary complete expression we want" but he never completely explains what this expression really means.

If i put in place of A , "It is raining." what is the proof and even if we say proof is just seeing out of the window, what is the corresponding lambda expression / term and type ??

Can someone explain it ?

Comment: please be more specific about where you found this in ML's writings.  If A is a proposition then "a:A" means that a is a proof of A.

Comment: page 17 and 18 of what???

Comment: I have half a dozen papers by ML.  is it really too hard for you to give us a title at the least?

Comment: previously i have mentioned.  in "on the meanings of logical constant"   Per martin lof. pdf https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~crary/819-f09/Martin-Lof83.pdf

Comment: thank you, but in fact you did not previously mention that.

Comment: Sorry for that. I did mention the name of the writing but forgot to give the link and page numbers. Added now.

Comment: no prob.  but please update your question with a ref or link.